# Click a button using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have the below HTML code

```
<footer class="aui-dialog2-footer">
<div class="aui-dialog2-footer-actions">
  <button class=" aui-button aui-button-primary dialog-submit"  resolved="">
      Add key
    </button>
    <button class=" aui-button aui-button-link dialog-cancel" resolved="">Cancel</button>
```

Here is the attached image 
[image]

I want to click this button using selenium. I have written

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]").click()
```

But this is not clicking the button. I have used find_element_by_class_name but it shows it can't resolve class name. How can I click this button using selenium.

Comment: Have you determine whether the problem is that it's not finding the element, or that it's finding the element but the click does nothing?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, it is not clicking the button and throws error it is unable to find find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]") element

Comment: Your XPath looks correct to me. Is the element in an iframe?

Comment: @gtlambert My element is in popup window

Comment: You will need to use `driver.switch_to`

Comment: @gtlambert But I have one more element in popup window. I am accessing it as driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//textarea[@name='key'])[2]").send_keys('key added'). It is working fine.

Comment: Either way, we need more information. Your XPath is correct.

Comment: @gtlambert I have edited the question

Comment: @gtlambert it's not a real popup window, you cannot use `driver.switch_to` with that. 
@Vivek Puri: wait for window before you try to access any elements within it. E.g. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]"))`

Answer (score 0):

looks like its in other iFrame look if yes just switch to it